# GPS in window phone (movement from current position when i am move on the way. how?)

Tags: geolocation, windows-phone, bing-maps

i am working with GPS in windows phone 7.1, i got the current position on bing map and get the nearest Restaurants showing on bing map. but now i want that when am moving on the way then my pushpin where show me is also move  with me.
i.e. current position also want to change with my movement.

Answer (score 0):

I hope [this](http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Windows-Phone-Map-Control-Display-Current-Location-and-Remove-previous-Pushpins) to help you. In a nutshell, you have to use object `GeoCoordinateWatcher`.

```
private void startLocationButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (watcher == null)
    {
        watcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher(GeoPositionAccuracy.Default);
        watcher.MovementThreshold = 20;
        watcher.StatusChanged += new EventHandler<GeoPositionStatusChangedEventArgs>(watcher_StatusChanged);
        watcher.PositionChanged += new EventHandler<GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate>>(watcher_PositionChanged);

    }
    watcher.Start();
}

void watcher_StatusChanged(object sender, GeoPositionStatusChangedEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.Status)
    {
        case GeoPositionStatus.Disabled:
            MessageBox.Show("Location Service is not enabled on the device");
            break;

        case GeoPositionStatus.NoData:
            MessageBox.Show(" The Location Service is working, but it cannot get location data.");
            break;
    }
}

void watcher_PositionChanged(object sender, GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate> e)
{
    if (e.Position.Location.IsUnknown)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please wait while your prosition is determined....");
        return;
    }
}
```